# One channel per task to track all discussions related to particular tasks in Slack: good or bad idea?

Tags: tracking

Wanting to quickly see everything that has been said regarding a particular task is very common. And often impossible, because both channels and PM contain discussions about multiple tasks. Therefore, not only discussions about a particular task come in pieces, these pieces are mixed with pieces related to other tasks!

Having one channel per task seems aberrant, but it effectively solves this problem. Has anyone tried something like this? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Tracking responses at the task level in a tool such as Slack defeats the purpose of the 'project team', whereby active and open communication are key.  Individual task discussions should happen verbally, better yet in-person (if possible).  I've seen success in using Slack to track team discussions by product Feature, whereby the team agrees at the project outset ("team agreements") to review posts daily and verbally communicate in the daily stand-up, or in outside team collaboration.